# Integration over R/lZ

Tags: integration, group-theory, lebesgue-integral

Im confused about integration over a factor group.

I have given a function $f:\mathbb{R}/l\mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ parameterized by arc length, i.e $\Vert f^{\prime}(x) \Vert$ = 1 for all $x \in \mathbb{R}/l\mathbb{Z}$. That means also that the total length of $f$ has to be $l$.

I know using $f:\mathbb{R}/l\mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ means also that the function is $l$-periodic.

If i'd like to calculate the total length of the curve $f$ i have to evaluate
$$\int \limits_{\mathbb{R}/l\mathbb{Z}} \underbrace{\Vert f^{\prime}(\tau) \Vert}_{=1} d\mu(\tau) = \mu(\mathbb{R}/l\mathbb{Z}) = l$$

I don't understand why $\mu(\mathbb{R}/l\mathbb{Z}) = l$ and how to handle integration over $\mathbb{R}/l\mathbb{Z}$.

Can someone explain to me how to handle this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many possible choices for $\mu$ but the obvious one is $\int_{\Bbb{R/lZ}} gd\mu = \int_0^l g(x)dx$ ie. inherited from the Lebesgue measure of $\Bbb{R}$, which gives a Haar measure on the quotient.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i don't understand exactly what you mean. Can you go a bit more into detail ? 
I supposed anyway that $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. Do you mean by dx the new measure (Haar measure ?). 
And how you get then that you integrate over [0,l]?

Comment: $\int_0^1 g(x)dx$ is a standard integral on a real interval.